# uint multiplication with fractions in solidity

Tags: solidity

I am trying to get a lower and upper threshold on a value in solidity.

```
function foo(uint value) public {

  uint lower_threshold = value * 0.5;
  uint upper_threshold = value * 1.5;

}
```

With the above code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Operator * not compatible with types uint32 and rational_const 1 / 2
```

My goal is to check that the value passed is within the threshold to perform some action. Is there a way to do this in Solidity?

Comment: You may find useful Mikhail Vladimirov's Math in Solidity series, particularly [Part 1: Numbers](https://medium.com/coinmonks/math-in-solidity-part-1-numbers-384c8377f26d) and [Part 2: Overflow](https://medium.com/coinmonks/math-in-solidity-part-2-overflow-3cd7283714b4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentions](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#fixed-point-numbers) says **Solidity** does not fully support decimal operations yet. You have two options there.

1. You can convert `.5` and `1.5` into `multiplication` and `division` operations. But as output will be uint you will have precision loss. **Ex:**

   ```
   uint value = 5;
   uint lower_threshold = value / 2;//output 2
   uint upper_threshold = value * 3 / 2;//output 7
   ```
2. You can multiply `value` with some `uint value` so that performing
   `value / 2` won't have any precision loss. **Ex:**

   ```
   uint value = 5;
   uint tempValue = value * 10;//output 50
   uint lower_threshold = tempValue / 2;//output 25
   uint upper_threshold = tempValue * 3 / 2;//output 75

   if(tempValue >= lower_threshold && tempValue <= lower_threshold) {
       //do some stuff
   }
   ```